# Do subsequent calls to sess.run() erase state?

Tags: tensorflow

Suppose my computation graph has only 2 nodes. Node 1 --> Node 2 (Node1's output is Node2's input. Node2 also operates on Node1's input.)
Computation graph looks like:

```
x = Node1(z)

y = Node2(x, z)
```

Now if I Run Node1 using sess.run and then run Node2 using a different sess.run call, would the *state*, as in `x` be preserved across the calls or would `x` be computed from scratch in second call?

Comment: at least, it is preserved for s.run([x, y])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, unless you [assign it to a `tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable.assign) or [enqueue it in a queue](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#QueueBase.enqueue), TensorFlow will discard the value of all intermediate tensors used when computing the result of [`Session.run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/client.html#Session.run) as soon as they are no longer needed, to free up memory.

One exception to this rule is that, if in your program `z` is a constant tensor, and `Node1()` is a stateless operation (i.e. a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function)), TensorFlow may cache the result of `Node1()` as part of a [constant folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) optimization. This optimization can make subsequent executions of `Session.run()` faster, at the expense of some extra work on the first run. However, if `z` is a a variable, or `Node1()` is a stateful operation, then TensorFlow cannot safely cache the result, and it will be re-evaluated on each `Session.run()` call. (Also, TensorFlow currently performs constant folding anew for each distinct set of arguments to `Session.run()`, so the value for `x` computed when you run `Node1()` only would not be reused in the constant folding for `Node2()`. This optimisation could be added in the future, however.)